# cycle ERROR @firebase/firestore: Firestore (9.17.1): Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, expo

I am getting this error and I have no idea what's wrong, my conncetion is strong

```
cycle.
 ERROR @firebase/firestore: Firestore (9.17.1): Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Backend didn't respond within 10 seconds.
This typically indicates that your device does not have a healthy Internet connection at the moment. The client will operate in offline mode until it is able to successful
```

my code

```
  useEffect(() => {
      const writeToDatabase = async () => {
        const { name, email } = users;
        if (email) {
          try {
            const queryData = query(ref(database, 'users'), orderByChild('email'), b           equalTo(email));
            const snapshot = await get(queryData);
            const uuid = snapshot.exists() ? Object.keys(snapshot.val())[0] : uid();
            const userRef = ref(database, `/users/${uuid}`);
            const userData = {
              id: uuid,
              name: name,
              email: email,
              long: location.coords.longitude,
              lat: location.coords.latitude,
            };
            await set(userRef, userData);
            console.log('Write to database successful');
          } catch (error) {
            console.log('Error writing to database:', error);
          }
        }
      };
      writeToDatabase();
    }, [location, database, users]);
```

Database Rules
{
"rules": {
".read": true,
".write": true,
"users": {
".indexOn": "email"
},
}
}